# Installing CCR and DSS Runtime fails - Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio 4

Tags: ccr, robotics-studio

I want to install the Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio 4 and downloaded it directly from microsoft.com. When I run the .exe file a window pops up with the requirements that will be installed before installing the RDS:

- MS CCR and DSS Runtime
- NVIDIA Physx System Software

When I hit the Install Button the status of CCR/DSS Runtime switches from Pending to Installing and after 10 seceonds of loading or something an error message appears:

**"The files for installation requirement Microsoft CCR and DSS Runtime could not be found. The installation will now stop. This is probably due to a failed, or canceled download"**

I'm quite sure that the file is not broken (multiple times downloaded, filessize matches) and I fullfill all software requirements listed here: http://www.microsoft.com/robotics/#GetStartedStep2

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging an found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roboticsccr/thread/4215a6ea-4bf3-42c4-9902-5308cfbb70e9) under Social/MSDN:

Essentially:

1. Make sure .NET 3.5 sp1 is installed (.NET 4 won't do, it needs 3.5 sp1)
2. There are some reports of issues when installing in a path that contains non-english characters
3. There was one report saying that the person had to format/reinstal windows and then it worked fine

I know that this answer is incomplete at best but I'm hoping that it is a simple case of installing 3.5sp1.